# How do I get the URI that is needed for redirect URI authorization?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-redux, next-auth

I am using NextAuth to fir google sign in authorization and when I test it using localhost I end up getting this error, but the the URI is not stated. How do I find it?

[Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.

If you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.
Request details: redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWlcA.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect uri is the protocol and the domain and the port.

It should be exact as you mention in your Google Developer Console application settings.

E.g:
`redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000`

Also, make sure you use the correct
credientials of `client_id` that is required on both ends of client and the server side, and the `secret` at the server side.

You can learn more here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server